# Possible overdraw: Root element paints background in Theme.Holo

Tags: android, android-theme

I have read similar questions for this problem but i couldn't find my answer anywhere. In order to solve the overdraw problem i use the following:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

When i use this in my activity which has an `ActionBar`, the background color of the action bar also changes to null. How can i fix this? If i set the color of the action bar separate the blue divider is being disappeared. How can i set to null the background of the frame below to action bar divider?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following:

Create 2 separate themes: one for the activity with the action bar, the other one for the one  without it.

For the activity without the action bar, use the theme you provided in your post, i.e.:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

For the activity with the action bar, simply create a theme which doesn't have the `android:windowBackground` item but instead sets a specific background colour that you want to have in that activity. Then, in the layout file that you inflate for the activity, delete the `android:background` attribute (because it'll already be set by the theme).

To make it a bit more visual, the theme would look like this maybe:

```
<style name="MyThemeForActivityWithoutActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

And the activity's layout would maybe look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" // remove this
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

I indicated which line I'd remove in the snippet above.

Does this help? :)

Answer (score 0):

Solve your overdraw problem in a different way. Set the background you need in `android:windowBackground` and instead remove backgrounds from your layouts. Then you'll get action bar background back.

Using null window background is a bad solution anyway, exactly because it causes unintended side-effects, like rendering artifacts (or in your case missing action bar background). Chet Haase explains it in detail in [Developing for Android VIII
The Rules: User Interface](https://medium.com/google-developers/developing-for-android-viii-e91ced595fac#.4700m4eb3):

> **Avoid Null Window Backgrounds**
>
> One technique to avoid overdraw is to eliminate the window background
>   in situations where the views in the hierarchy all have opaque
>   backgrounds. That is, the user will not see the background of the
>   window if the view hierarchy completely covers that background with
>   one or more opaque views.
>
> Eliminating the window background can be a valid technique, but it
>   tends to be a complicated way to solve overdraw issues, and can often
>   result in rendering artifacts in different situations. While it is
>   possible to set a null window background in the application manifest,
>   this can result in graphics artifacts due to the system not being able
>   to draw the starting window correctly. A more correct way to do this
>   is to leave the starting window background in place in the manifest,
>   but set it to null in the activity’s onCreate() method, by calling
>   getWindow().setBackground(null). But even this approach can cause
>   artifacts. For example, if the keyboard/IME is set to adjustResize and
>   is then animated in for an activity that has a null background, there
>   may be artifacts behind the keyboard as it animates in because the
>   window manager has nothing to draw for that background. Also,
>   fullscreen ListViews may have artifacts with overscroll bounce gaps
>   (which can be worked around with
>   ListView.setOverscrollFooter/Header()).
>
> The correct way to address overdraw issues for this situation is to
>   actually use the starting window. Instead of having containers with
>   their own opaque background color between the window background and
>   views, put the background drawable you want on the window itself with
>   the windowBackground theme attribute and let those intervening
>   containers keep their default transparent backgrounds.